# Painting the planks

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are n planks put together in a row. Adjacent planks have no gap between them. The planks are numbered from the left to the right starting from one, the $i^{th}$ plank has the width of $1$ meter and the height of $a_i$ meters.

We also have a brush of width 1 meter. We can make vertical and horizontal strokes with the brush. During a stroke the brush's full surface must touch the fence at all the time (see the samples for the better understanding). Note that you are allowed to paint the same area of the fence multiple times.

What is the minimum number of steps needed to paint all the planks?

[image]

In the above figure, planks of size $4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4$ are placed from left to right. If we paint horizontally starting from first plank on the left at height 3, then we need two steps to paint the row(there cannot be a hole in a horizontal stroke).

I am not able to think how to approach this problem as my discrete mathematics is very weak. What deductions can I make so that I can solve the problem?(Note that I don't need a solution, rather find some arguments / lemmas so that I eventually arrive at a solution.

One trivial argument is "upper bound on minimum number of steps is the total number of planks" as we can paint all of the planks vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve the problem via dynamic programming, which means we memoize the answers to states representing subproblems which are smaller and easier to solve, to try to construct a solution to a bigger problem.

**Cases:**

> Firstly, we ask ourselves, how do we make sure every plank is painted? If the optimal solution requires a plank to be painted vertically, we can extend the stroke used to paint the plank vertically until it paints the entire plank. Hence, for each plank, we either paint it vertically, which ensures that it will be painted, or we paint it horizontally. When we paint it vertically, we use $1$ step. When we paint it horizontally, we use $a_i$ steps, where $a_i$ is the height of the plank. The benefit of painting a plank horizontally is when there are planks which can be fully painted when this plank is painted horizontally.

**Order of processing:**

> To solve the problem in a tractable way, we think of an order to process the planks in. The two most intuitive orders are left to right (right to left is the same) and from the shortest to longest (or from the bottom to top). Longest to shortest does not seem a viable way to process the planks as taking a set of longest planks and filling them vertically would cause the state to hold a subset of planks, making the computational time possibly infeasible.

**Shortest to Longest:**

> If we process the planks from shortest to longest, the shortest plank would split planks into 2 sections. If we choose to let the shortest plank $a_i$ to be painted horizontally, then we can reduce the problem into $2$ (or more) smaller problems, by imagining taking off the lower $a_i$ rows.

**Transition for Shortest to Longest:**

> If we choose to paint the shortest plank vertically, then the other planks in the subproblem should also be painted vertically, else if one of them is painted horizontally, it would paint this shortest plank horizontally as well. The state of the problem becomes $3$ parameters, the start of the subproblem, and the end of the subproblem, and the number of rows from the bottom which are already painted. We can drop the parameter of the number of rows covered by the earlier subproblem as this can be recovered as the largest plank smaller than all the planks in the subarray.

**Left to Right:**

> Here, we process the planks from left to right. In order to create a state for the partially painted fence, we note that the rows painted horizontally start from the base of the fences and end at some height. It does not make sense to skip a row as any fence taller than the skipped row will not be fully painted. When we partially paint the fence, we ensure that all the planks to the left are fully painted.
>  Hence, the state of the problem can be summarised into $2$ parameters, the number of fences painted from the left, and the number of horizontal rows painted. As the heights of the fence may grow arbitrarily large, it is more efficient to store which fence's height the number of horizontal rows follow.

**Transition for Left to Right:**

> If the height of the current plank is less than or equal to the number of horizontal rows painted, we change the number of horizontal rows painted to the height of the current plank. Else, we have a choice. We can either choose to paint the plank vertically, incurring one step, or paint it horizontally, incurring $a_i-r$ steps, where $a_i$ is the height of the current plank, and $r$ is the number of rows painted. This increases the number of rows painted to $a_i$.

Comment: "For each plank, we either paint it vertically, or we paint it horizontally." Does this mean if it is painted horizontally we will have at least h steps where h is the height of the plank?

Comment: Actually I wanted to know the thoughts on the problem rather than the solution itself(since I am not able to make arguments in the first place how would I solve it?) If you instead show some "deductions" or "arguments", that would be more helpful to me i.e. how did you think when you first saw the problem? What ideas came to your mind that helped you create the solution?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am at the end of understanding your analysis except I can't prove why this argument is true "For each plank, we either paint it vertically or we paint it horizontally". I mean, why can't there be such sequence in which we have "paint first 2 units of plank using a single vertical stroke, then paint 3rd row horizontally to the 5th plank and so on...

Comment: @nitrogen I added something addressing your concerns.

Comment: This question made me feel dumb. I think my skill has saturated. By the way, how do you rate this problem on a scale of 1 to 10? Sometimes you are so confused that you don't even know what you are confused about :D Thanks for your elaborate explanation.

Comment: Don't worry, after you learn to solve a question you think is tedious, you are likely to feel you have learnt some techniques allowing you to understand other questions you have solved before better.